# couldn't load TLS file database

Tags: ssl, web, networking, embedded, midori

I have a customed device with iMx.6 microcontroller and embedded Linux. Also I have costumed Linux kernel according in hardware and rootFS built by buildroot. The device has a LVDS and touchscreen. I would like to have Midori browser in the device to browse various websites. the problem is when I run Midori with $midori -a [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) I got this error :

GLib-Net-WARNING **: couldn't load TLS file database: Failed to open file '/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt': No such file or directory

Do you have any idea how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Midori cannot find the file containing the set of X.509 public key Certificates of the Certificate Authorities it should trust. Since it cannot find it, it does not trust any Public Key Certificate presented by the WEB sites it tries to connect to using TLS.

You would need to retrieve such a file, for example from the cURL project, [cacert.pem](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem), and install it in the `/etc/pki/tls/certs` directory - create it if it does not exist - under the name `ca-bundle.crt`.

This should solve your issue.